# Count customer that have >10 transaction with us, excluding returns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given the task to find the count of customers that have > 10 transactions. I have tried and the code is show below:

```
select 
count(*) as Customer_More_10_Transaction
from dbo.Transactions
group by cust_id
having count (*) > 10
```

The output just show the transaction of customer and not count the customer with > 10 transaction. I expected the output to show 36.

The output shown:

```
12
11
11
11
12
11
11
12
11
11
12
11
11
11
12
11
12
13
11
11
11
12
11
11
11
12
11
11
11
11
11
11
12
13
11
11
```

Actual output needed:

```
36
```

Comment: Why do you expect

Comment: you said `not count the customer with > 10 transaction`. But your query `group by cust_id having count (*) > 10` means you are looking for `cust_id` with more than 10 `transactions`. Also the title of this thread stated `excluding returns` but i don't see that handle in your query

Comment: You never specified how to identify returns.  We can't guess your table structure so you have to include that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

you also need to count your result.

```
SELECT count(*) as Count_Of_Customer_More_10_Transaction FROM
(
  select 
  count(*) as Customer_More_10_Transaction
  from    dbo.Transactions
  group by cust_id
  having count (*) > 10
) AS T
```

Answer (score 2):

We can handle your requirement without a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_cnt
FROM dbo.Transactions
GROUP BY cust_id
HAVING COUNT (*) > 10;
```

Comment: My answers are nowhere near top today TBH.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT cust_id 
    FROM  dbo.Transactions
    group by cust_id
    having count (*) > 10
) AS T
```

Get the list of `custid` with transaction more than 10 and count it.

Comment: you missed the alias for the derived table

Comment: @Squirrel : Alias need could vary from DB to DB. However thanks for pointing out , I have corrected my response.

Comment: as far as I know `SQL Server` required an alias.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(*)
FROM transactionlogs
WHERE UserId is not null 
GROUP BY UserId HAVING COUNT (*) > 10;
```

Comment: Can you please kindly explain your query. Also what makes you add the condition `WHERE UserId is not null` ?

Comment: And where does `UserId` come from?

Comment: Also where does the table `transactionlogs` come from ?

Comment: a transaction logs will be kept for every successful transaction with for its particular userid.

Comment: i am keeping a table (transactionlogs) of evry transaction occurs on my website or application. Then i apply this query over transactionlogs table

Comment: what does this `transactionlogs` got to do with OP's question ?

Comment: it is just a table name i have used the name transactionlogs some other buddy can use it as Dbo.Orders or some else where the user kept its completed orders.